# Strange query, not sure if this needs to be nested? What's wrong here?

Tags: mysql, sql

What's wrong with this query? (in general)

I've researched everything I can, but no dice... I'm out of luck. Any help?

```
SELECT uid, AVG(ttl) AS average_order_ttl
FROM Invoices_temp
HAVING COUNT(order_id) >= 1
```

Comment: Please explain what the query is supposed to be doing.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT UserId, AVG(Total) AS AvgOrderTotal
FROM Invoices
GROUP BY UserId
HAVING COUNT(OrderId) >= 1;
```

That said, `OrderId` is probably never `NULL`, so I think the `HAVING` clause is superfluous.